# Persisting Dynamic Table Across postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

I have a table which is created in the code behind. In the vb code the table is populated based on the data returned from a query when a combobox value is selected. The code creates a row with two cells one for a label and one for a drop down list for each row in the data. I'm having trouble preserving the selected drop down list values that are created for each row after postback.

When the table is initially populated I store the data in a ViewState value and recreate the table based on these settings in PageLoad. The problem is every time I change values for the drop downs and then cause a postback to happen by clicking save settings all of the settings are incorrectly saved because they are reverted before the save is even called.

I'm looking to maintain the values across postbacks but still update the values from the database when a new account is selected. I've attempted several ways to do this and experienced two issues with my code:

When I have EnableViewState = "true" on the table in markup:
When I select an item from the combobox to select a new account the selected values in the drop down lists are remaining when they should clear at this time and use the new database values.

When I have EnableViewState = "false" on the table in markup:
Any postback resets the dropdownlists to their database values. Even clicking "Save" which immediately postsback to save the values to the database will just resave their current database values and ignore the selected values.

code behind:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports Telerik.Web.UI

Public Class AccountSettings2
    Inherits Page

    Private _selectedAccountID As Integer
    Protected _truckPermissions As List(Of PermissionData2)

    Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        _truckPermissions = New List(Of PermissionData2)

        If Not IsNothing(Session("SelectedAccountID")) Then
            _selectedAccountID = Session("SelectedAccountID")
        End If

        If Not IsPostBack Then

            Dim dtAccounts As New DataTable("Accounts")
            Dim col1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
            col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
            col1.ColumnName = "AccountID"
            dtAccounts.Columns.Add(col1)
            Dim col2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
            col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
            col2.ColumnName = "Name"
            dtAccounts.Columns.Add(col2)

            Dim row1 As DataRow
            Dim row2 As DataRow
            Dim row3 As DataRow
            Dim row4 As DataRow
            row1 = dtAccounts.NewRow()
            row1("AccountID") = 1
            row1("Name") = "Account 1"
            dtAccounts.Rows.Add(row1)
            row2 = dtAccounts.NewRow()
            row2("AccountID") = 2
            row2("Name") = "Account 2"
            dtAccounts.Rows.Add(row2)
            row3 = dtAccounts.NewRow()
            row3("AccountID") = 3
            row3("Name") = "Account 3"
            dtAccounts.Rows.Add(row3)
            row4 = dtAccounts.NewRow()
            row4("AccountID") = 4
            row4("Name") = "Account 4"
            dtAccounts.Rows.Add(row4)

            rcbAccounts.DataValueField = "AccountID"
            rcbAccounts.DataTextField = "Name"
            rcbAccounts.DataSource = dtAccounts
            rcbAccounts.DataBind()

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            If _selectedAccountID > 0 Then
                rcbAccounts.SelectedValue = _selectedAccountID
                SelectAccount(_selectedAccountID)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

#Region "UI Updates"

    Private Sub SelectAccount(accountID As Integer)

        _selectedAccountID = accountID
        Session("SelectedAccountID") = accountID
        CreateTruckPermissionsData(accountID)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateTruckPermissionsData(accessTypeID As Integer)

        tblTruckPermissions.Rows.Clear()

        _truckPermissions.Add(New PermissionData2(1, "Permission 1", "Permission 1", accessTypeID))
        _truckPermissions.Add(New PermissionData2(2, "Permission 2", "Permission 2", accessTypeID))
        _truckPermissions.Add(New PermissionData2(3, "Permission 3", "Permission 3", accessTypeID))
        _truckPermissions.Add(New PermissionData2(4, "Permission 4", "Permission 4", accessTypeID))
        ViewState("_truckPermissions") = _truckPermissions

        Dim dtAccessTypes As New DataTable("AccessTypes")
        Dim col1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
        col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
        col1.ColumnName = "AccessTypeID"
        dtAccessTypes.Columns.Add(col1)
        Dim col2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
        col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        col2.ColumnName = "Description"
        dtAccessTypes.Columns.Add(col2)

        Dim row1 As DataRow
        Dim row2 As DataRow
        Dim row3 As DataRow
        Dim row4 As DataRow
        row1 = dtAccessTypes.NewRow()
        row1("AccessTypeID") = 1
        row1("Description") = "Type 1"
        dtAccessTypes.Rows.Add(row1)

        row2 = dtAccessTypes.NewRow()
        row2("AccessTypeID") = 2
        row2("Description") = "Type 2"
        dtAccessTypes.Rows.Add(row2)
        row3 = dtAccessTypes.NewRow()
        row3("AccessTypeID") = 3
        row3("Description") = "Type 3"
        dtAccessTypes.Rows.Add(row3)
        row4 = dtAccessTypes.NewRow()
        row4("AccessTypeID") = 4
        row4("Description") = "Type 4"
        dtAccessTypes.Rows.Add(row4)

        For Each pd As PermissionData2 In _truckPermissions
            Dim tr As New TableRow()
            Dim td As New TableCell()
            Dim td2 As New TableCell()
            Dim l As New Label()
            Dim ddl As New RadDropDownList()

            l.Text = pd.Name
            ddl.ID = "ddlTruckPermission" + pd.ID.ToString()
            ddl.DataTextField = "Description"
            ddl.DataValueField = "AccessTypeID"
            ddl.DataSource = dtAccessTypes
            ddl.DataBind()
            ddl.SelectedValue = pd.HasAccess

            td.Controls.Add(l)
            td2.Controls.Add(ddl)
            tr.Cells.Add(td)
            tr.Cells.Add(td2)

            tblTruckPermissions.Rows.Add(tr)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshTruckSettings()

        If _selectedAccountID = 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        For Each r As TableRow In tblTruckPermissions.Rows
            For Each c As Control In r.Cells(1).Controls
                If c.ID.Contains("ddlTruckPermission") Then
                    Dim ddl As RadDropDownList = DirectCast(c, RadDropDownList)

                    Dim pd As PermissionData2 = _truckPermissions.Find(Function(x) x.ID = Integer.Parse(ddl.ID.Substring(0 + "ddlTruckPermission".Length, ddl.ID.Length - "ddlTruckPermission".Length)))

                    If Not IsNothing(pd) Then
                        ddl.SelectedValue = pd.HasAccess
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Events"

    Protected Sub btnSavePermissions_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If _selectedAccountID > 0 Then

            Dim permissionUpdates As List(Of PermissionUpdate) = New List(Of PermissionUpdate)()

            For Each r As TableRow In tblTruckPermissions.Rows
                For Each c As Control In r.Cells(1).Controls
                    If c.ID.Contains("ddlTruckPermission") Then
                        Dim ddl As RadDropDownList = DirectCast(c, RadDropDownList)
                        permissionUpdates.Add(New PermissionUpdate(Integer.Parse(ddl.ID.LastIndexOf("ddlTruckPermission")), False, ddl.SelectedValue))
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            ' Code to save permissions to database

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub rcbAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs)

        Dim newIndex As Integer

        If (Integer.TryParse(e.Value, newIndex)) Then
            SelectAccount(newIndex)
        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class


<Serializable>
Public Class PermissionData2

    Private _id As Integer
    Private _name As String
    Private _description As String
    Private _hasAccess As Integer

    Public Property ID() As Integer

        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String

        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Property Description() As String

        Get
            Return _description
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _description = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Property HasAccess() As Integer

        Get
            Return _hasAccess
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _hasAccess = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Sub New()

        _id = 0
        _name = Name
        _description = Description
        _hasAccess = 0

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(id As Integer, name As String, description As String, hasAccess As Integer)

        _id = id
        _name = name
        _description = description
        _hasAccess = hasAccess

    End Sub

End Class
```

aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="AccountSettings2.aspx.vb" Inherits="AccountSettings2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />
    <title>Account Settings</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbAccounts" runat="server" Height="200" Width="200"
            DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled" EmptyMessage="Select an Account" HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
            EnableLoadOnDemand="true" Filter="Contains"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack ="true"
            Label="Accounts: " Skin="Office2010Silver" />

        <asp:Table ID="tblTruckPermissions" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnSavePermissions" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSavePermissions_Click" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much better way to handle my scenario. I used the repeater control to handle almost all of the code instead of trying to do it manually. I used http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-4_2900_ to help guide me. Thank you to Casey Crookston for much help in working on this.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTruckPermissions" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemDataBound="rptTruckPermissions_ItemDataBound">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <table>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PermissionName") %></td>
                                    <td><telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTruckPermissionAccessTypes" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </table>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then

            If Not IsNothing(_accountDetails) Then
                SelectAccount(_accountDetails.AccountID)
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

Private Sub SelectAccount(accountID As Integer)

        _selectedAccountID = accountID
        Session("SelectedAccountID") = accountID

        BindTruckPermissions()


    End Sub

    Private Sub BindTruckPermissions()

        rptTruckPermissions.DataSource = GetPermissionData(_selectedAccountID, PermissionCategory.Truck)
        rptTruckPermissions.DataBind()

    End Sub

Protected Sub rptTruckPermissions_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

            Dim r As DataRowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
            Dim ddl As RadDropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlTruckPermissionAccessTypes"), RadDropDownList)
            Select Case r("PermissionTypeID")

                Case PermissionType.LegacyBasic
                    ddl.DataSource = GetLegacyWebAccessTypes(PermissionType.LegacyBasic)
                Case PermissionType.LegacyPublisher
                    ddl.DataSource = GetLegacyWebAccessTypes(PermissionType.LegacyPublisher)
            End Select

            'ddl.ID = "ddlTruckPermission" + pd.ID.ToString()
            ddl.DataTextField = "Description"
            ddl.DataValueField = "AccessTypeID"
            ddl.DataBind()

            If IsDBNull(r("AccessTypeID")) Then
                ddl.SelectedValue = LegacyWebAccessType.NoAccess
            Else
                ddl.SelectedValue = r("AccessTypeID")
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now that I have a look at everything, I've cleared out my original answer.  Here are some thoughts:

**First:**

I would take everything out of the Page_Init() method and move it into the Page_Load() method.  Page_Int() should be used sparingly, and I don't see a good reason to be using it here.  The problem with Page_Int() is that it gets fired too early in the life cycle of the page before most objects have been created, and so you end up with weird behavior that is hard to figure out.

I only ever use it for LOGIC that is pertinent to the page and needs to happen before the page loads,  but you should keep it free of anything to do with the actual page objects (buttons, data grids, etc).  I would not use it here.

Also, having "If Not IsPostBack Then" in side the Page_Int() method is pointless, because it only gets fired once before the page is initialized, and then never again.

**Second:**

Ok.  Session("SelectedAccountID").  Do you NEED to use a Session variable here?  Session variables maintain themselves across the entire website until the user closes the website.  If you need this to be a session level variable (used elsewhere on the site, other pages, etc), so be it.

Let's talk about _selectedAccountID.  Is it possible that Session("SelectedAccountID") may have been set someplace else in the website before loading this page?  That's what I am assuming, because Session("SelectedAccountID") is a Session variable.  I write the code below on that assumption, and that you want to use the value of Session("SelectedAccountID") to set the initial value of the dropdown.

From seeing how you use _selectedAccountID, it looks like you will initially populate it from Session("SelectedAccountID"). And that when the dropdown changes, you want to reset both _selectedAccountID and Session("SelectedAccountID") to the selected value.  Is this correct?  I wrote the code as if it were. See below for the best way to handle that.

Next, how you are using _truckPermissions is a little less clear. But it looks like you just need another ViewState variable.  See below.

Also, I like to order everything on the page in the order it will be called.  So, let's take a look....

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Telerik.Web.UI

Public Class AccountSettings2
Inherits Page

' This is your ViewState variable for selectedAccountID.  You will set it first in Page_Load() inside If Not IsPostback.  It can be access from any method in the code behind, and will persist across postbacks.
Public Property _selectedAccountID() As String
    Get
        Return ViewState("selectedAccountID").ToString()
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("selectedAccountID") = value
    End Set
End Property

' This is your ViewState variable for truckPermissions.  It can be access from any method in the code behind, and will persist across postbacks.
Public Property _truckPermissions() As List(Of PermissionData2)
    Get
        Return ViewState("truckPermissions")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of PermissionData2))
        ViewState("truckPermissions") = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Anything done inside this If Then will happen ONLY when the page loads for the first time. Never again.

        ' Set your initial value for the ViewState variable _selectedAccountID here  
        If Not IsNothing(Session("SelectedAccountID")) Then
            _selectedAccountID = Session("SelectedAccountID")
        Else
            _selectedAccountID = 0 ' Do you need to give this a default value is Session("SelectedAccountID") is empty?  If so, this will work.
        End If

        ' Create your DataTable, but to keep things easy to read inside Page_Load(), move the work to another method
        Dim dtAccounts As DataTable = BuildDataTable()

        ' Do this here, just to be clean
        rcbAccounts.DataValueField = "AccountID"
        rcbAccounts.DataTextField = "Name"
        rcbAccounts.DataSource = dtAccounts
        rcbAccounts.DataBind()

        ' Set the initial value on your dropdown.
        If _selectedAccountID > 0 Then
            rcbAccounts.SelectedValue = _selectedAccountID
            ' SelectAccount(_selectedAccountID) ' I don't think we want to do this here
            CreateTruckPermissionsData(_selectedAccountID) ' But I think we DO want to do this
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Function BuildDataTable() As DataTable

    Dim dtAccounts As New DataTable("Accounts")

    dtAccounts.Columns.Add(BuildDataColumn("System.Int32", "AccountID"))
    dtAccounts.Columns.Add(BuildDataColumn("System.String", "Name"))

    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 4
        row = dtAccounts.NewRow()
        row("AccountID") = i
        row("Name") = "Account " & i
        dtAccounts.Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    Return dtAccounts

End Function

Private Function BuildDataColumn(DataType As String, ColumnName As String) As DataColumn
    Dim newCol As New DataColumn()
    newCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType(DataType)
    newCol.ColumnName = ColumnName
    Return newCol
End Function

#Region "Events"

Protected Sub btnSavePermissions_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If _selectedAccountID > 0 Then

        Dim permissionUpdates As List(Of PermissionUpdate) = New List(Of PermissionUpdate)()

        For Each r As TableRow In tblTruckPermissions.Rows
            For Each c As Control In r.Cells(1).Controls
                If c.ID.Contains("ddlTruckPermission") Then
                    Dim ddl As RadDropDownList = DirectCast(c, RadDropDownList)
                    permissionUpdates.Add(New PermissionUpdate(Integer.Parse(ddl.ID.LastIndexOf("ddlTruckPermission")), False, ddl.SelectedValue))
                End If
            Next
        Next

        ' Code to save permissions to database

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub rcbAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs)
    Dim newIndex As Integer
    If (Integer.TryParse(e.Value, newIndex)) Then
        SelectAccount(newIndex)
    End If
End Sub

#End Region



#Region "UI Updates"

Private Sub SelectAccount(accountID As Integer)
    _selectedAccountID = accountID
    Session("SelectedAccountID") = accountID
    CreateTruckPermissionsData(accountID)
End Sub

Private Sub CreateTruckPermissionsData(accessTypeID As Integer)
    ' this code can be cleaned up too, like I did for building the other table.  I just didn't have time to get to it.
    tblTruckPermissions.Rows.Clear()

    _truckPermissions.Add(New PermissionData2(1, "Permission 1", "Permission 1", accessTypeID))
    _truckPermissions.Add(New PermissionData2(2, "Permission 2", "Permission 2", accessTypeID))
    _truckPermissions.Add(New PermissionData2(3, "Permission 3", "Permission 3", accessTypeID))
    _truckPermissions.Add(New PermissionData2(4, "Permission 4", "Permission 4", accessTypeID))
    ViewState("_truckPermissions") = _truckPermissions

    Dim dtAccessTypes As New DataTable("AccessTypes")
    Dim col1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
    col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
    col1.ColumnName = "AccessTypeID"
    dtAccessTypes.Columns.Add(col1)
    Dim col2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
    col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
    col2.ColumnName = "Description"
    dtAccessTypes.Columns.Add(col2)

    Dim row1 As DataRow
    Dim row2 As DataRow
    Dim row3 As DataRow
    Dim row4 As DataRow
    row1 = dtAccessTypes.NewRow()
    row1("AccessTypeID") = 1
    row1("Description") = "Type 1"
    dtAccessTypes.Rows.Add(row1)

    row2 = dtAccessTypes.NewRow()
    row2("AccessTypeID") = 2
    row2("Description") = "Type 2"
    dtAccessTypes.Rows.Add(row2)
    row3 = dtAccessTypes.NewRow()
    row3("AccessTypeID") = 3
    row3("Description") = "Type 3"
    dtAccessTypes.Rows.Add(row3)
    row4 = dtAccessTypes.NewRow()
    row4("AccessTypeID") = 4
    row4("Description") = "Type 4"
    dtAccessTypes.Rows.Add(row4)

    For Each pd As PermissionData2 In _truckPermissions
        Dim tr As New TableRow()
        Dim td As New TableCell()
        Dim td2 As New TableCell()
        Dim l As New Label()
        Dim ddl As New RadDropDownList()

        l.Text = pd.Name
        ddl.ID = "ddlTruckPermission" + pd.ID.ToString()
        ddl.DataTextField = "Description"
        ddl.DataValueField = "AccessTypeID"
        ddl.DataSource = dtAccessTypes
        ddl.DataBind()
        ddl.SelectedValue = pd.HasAccess

        td.Controls.Add(l)
        td2.Controls.Add(ddl)
        tr.Cells.Add(td)
        tr.Cells.Add(td2)

        tblTruckPermissions.Rows.Add(tr)
    Next

End Sub


#End Region
```

Comment: I was under the impression that when creating objects dynamically in code-behind you must recreate them on every postback as well, is that incorrect?

Comment: No!  Not correct.  That's the entire point of ViewState.  You create them once, when the page loads.  Then they persist in ViewState across postbacks.  Trust me.  Put this If-Then in place, and see what happens.  You will be happy with the results.  EVERY Page_Load() method on EVERY page should have this If-Then.  EVERY TIME :-)

Comment: When I change it to include the If Not IsPostback - the table is empty after each postback.

Comment: Can we somehow see ALL of your code? In front and behind?  Also, (and I maybe was not clear on this) in your Page_Load, you DO need to distinguish between code that should only run once (create and initally populate your objects) and the code that should run after a postback (handle postback info, etc). Structure your If Not IsPostback accordingly.  When in doubt, put a breakpoint on the Page_Load method and step through it in debug to see exactly what is happening

Comment: Sure I will have the code posted here in about an hour

Comment: Also, are you sure that rcbAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged() is actually ever being hit?  Normally such a method would also have a HANDLES clause after it.  I'll edit my answer above so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for the help thus far. Yes the event is being hit because I have the handler declared in the markup: OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged". I have updated the original post to include a sample page that should be self sufficient to run.

Comment: Question:  How is RefreshTruckSettings() being used?  You declare the method, but you never call it.

Comment: RefreshTruckSettings() is not used in this simplified example; I should have deleted it. It is for a button that will refresh the screen to match the database but it was not necessary here.

Comment: hey man, I gota run.  I'm almost done looking at your code and working with it. Wanted to finish before I had to go for the day. I will get back to you probably tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, just kidding.  See the answer above.  I *think* I understood your intent.  Hope so. If not, maybe it will at least help get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Take your time, I will be done for the day at work, but checking this question for updates and will be able to work from home on this.

Comment: When using this code after selecting an account again I am getting "Multiple controls with the same ID 'ddlTruckPermission3' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs." This was happening before and why I thought I couldn't use viewstate.